# Json referring font to different font error

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx

I'm still new in libgdx here.

I'm trying to use uiskin from libgdx repository. By the way, I currently have different font that I have already set up.

The `uiskin.json` located at `assets/ui/uiskin/uiskin.json`

and my font located at `assets/font/ken/ken-white.fnt`

the directory structure looks like this
[image]

When i try to run it, on Android, it says 
`com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: ui/uiskin/uiskin.json`

and many lines below it, and finally i found this line 
`Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Font file not found: ../../font/ken/ken-white.fnt`

So the question is, how could I refer to `ken-white.fnt` from `uiskin.json` correctly?

Comment: Can you pastebin uiskin file? Or maybe try experimenting with those "../" slashes?

Comment: Does libgdx require a static path? Try with the full path to see if it works, could be your system is just munging the path

Comment: @Kush here it is http://pastebin.com/qYK9w9Lv 
Actually i only change the line 2.. the rest of it remains the same like i got from github

Comment: @bakoyaro that's what i don't figure out yet.. hmm if i use static path, would that be a problem if i move my workspace to another folder? 

what do you mean by munging, by the way? :))

Comment: Skin file looks fine to me. Have you tried this with default.fnt(& default.png) using this directory structure? I mean copy both of these to ken folder and update skin file to default.fnt.

Comment: Try "font/ken/ken-white.fnt"

Comment: @thekucays - Using a static path would definitely break if you tried to move it to another workspace, but it's already broken ;-) Temporarily using a static path would at least allow you to verify that it works, and confirm that it's just a path issue. 'munge-ing' can be referred to as processing, or in some cases destroying data. Also, see noone's comment

Comment: @bakoyaro finally now it works.. there's no need to put "../../" on it! Thanks by the way :)

Comment: @noone ahh that's my bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you are using an `InternalFileHandleResolver` to resolve the filepaths. Its root is your `assets` folder, not the place where your skin file is at.

That's why you can use "absolute" filepaths, starting from your `assets` folder. In your case, that would be `font/ken/ken-white.fnt`.

You can read more about the file handling in libgdx [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling).